# In React, my <select> operator can change value once, but ONLY once

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-hooks, state, mern

Edit: Solved!  Both values are strings evaluating to true.  Changed the falsy option to `value=''` and everything works.

I'm creating a MERN app similar to a blog where users have the option to make an entry public or private.  Obviously, public entries are visible to all users while private entries are only visible to the user who makes it.

I have one element in my form that allows a user to set an entry as public or private.  This is controlled with a `<select>` element.  If the user leaves the `<select>` on "No", the form gets sent with a value of `false`.  If the user toggles the value of `<select>` to "Yes", the form gets sent with a value of `true`.  The problem is that once a user toggles the value to "Yes", it's can't be changed back.  The `<select>` can be changed back to "No" on the front end, of course.  But while the value being sent to the server can be toggled from `false` to `true`, it can't be toggled back to `false`.

Here's the code.  State being handled in the React component:

```
const [state, handleChange] = useForm({
    title: "",
    purpose: "",  
    generic: "Template",
    notes: "",
    sample: "Insert Code", 
    tags: [],
    isPrivate: false
})
```

Here's the `<select>` code:

```
<select id='isPrivate-selector'
        name='isPrivate'
        onChange={handleChange}>
    <option value='false' selected>No</option>
    <option value='true'>Yes</option>
</select>
```

useForm is defined elsewhere and imported:

```
export const useForm = (initialValues) => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState(initialValues)

    return [
        values, 
        (e, name) => {
            if(e.target) {
                setValues({
                    ...values, 
                    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
                })
            }
            // If statement expands hook to handle CodeEditor and SyntaxHighlighter dynamic state transfer
            else
                setValues({
                    ...values, 
                    [name]: e
                })

        }
    ]
}
```

Of note, I previously had a checkbox which was displaying the same behavior.  I switched from checkbox to drop-down hoping that would solve the issue but no luck on that.  And I know the form is successfully talking with React since I can toggle the value of `isPrivate` in one direction, but not the other.

Comment: `e.target.value` is always a string, and both the string `'true'` and the string `'false'` are both "truthy". You should parse the value as the correct type (e.g., `e.target.value === 'true'`).

Comment: That was it!  Thank you.  I'll work on a cleaner approach later but for the moment I have `<option value='' selected>No</option>` which is working.